# How do i calculate datafield in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

How do i calculate data field in crystal report

eg:

[number]    [name]  [pcount] [ifactor] [icount] [rcount] [rfactor]

801          sw       1.00    0.00      1.00     2.00     1.00
 801          sw       2.00    1.00      1.00     2.00     1.00

i want to display like this:

[number]  [name] [total]

801          sw   [(pcount*ifactor) + icount + (rcount/rfactor)]

please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

a formula will work, so will a SQL expression